# Using material-UI's Grid component, how do I nest a table within another table?

Tags: reactjs, grid, components, material-ui

I'm creating a React 16.13.0 application and attempting to use the material-ui Grid component.  I'm having trouble nesting a Grid within a Grid.  I want to nest this table

```
          <Grid container item spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={1}>Icon</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>mission pick up window {mission.pickUpLocation}</Grid>
          </Grid>
```

within a larger table.  In the above, I expect the "Icon" cell and the other cell to be on the same row. However, when I put it in a larger table

```
<Grid container spacing={1} alignItems="center">
  <React.Fragment key={`content-item-${mission.id}`}>
    <Grid container direction="column">
      <Grid item container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={1}>
          PICK Up
        </Grid>
        <Grid container item xs={1}>
          <Grid container item spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={1}>Icon</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>mission pick up window {mission.pickUpLocation}</Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container item spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={1}>Icon</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>mission pick up location {mission.pickUpLocation}</Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

the icon cell appears on top of the cell with the text "mission pick up window".

[image]

What's the right way to structure my Grid?

Answer (score 0):

Grid is not exactly a table, but if you want to nest grids you can just on the grid container inside the grid item:

```
  <Grid container spacing={3}>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
      This grid is nested:
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
      Here there is no nested grid:
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

You can see it in action here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-nested-grid-9s7lq?file=/demo.js

In your code you put a Grid-Item inside another Grid-Item (you shouldn't do this), and also a Grid-Container inside another Grid-Container (also not good).

In general this is what you need to remember:

- Grid container is the wrapper if the grid items.
- If you want to have a nested grid - put a new grid-container inside a grid-item, and use it just as the above.

Comment: Thanks @Dekel, the issue I was wrangling with is how do you have a nested grid but also have a row of multiple items in that grid?  In my attempt, the two items are getting created in two rows but I want them in just one.

Comment: @Dave I think my example shows you how to handle this. If not please let me know.